# Как привести к единому виду номера телефонов?

Tags: python

Как привести к единому виду?

8 (963) 672-22-29  номера -->

```
numbers = """89636722229
7 963 6722229
+7 911 12312 18
79152211142
8 (912) 112 34 55
  8 (912) 112 3456
+7 (912) 112 34 57  
+7 (912) 112 34 57
(912) 112 34 57
12313123123
12"""
```

Comment: Подсказка: удалить все не цифры, затем просто пройтись и добавить нужные знаки

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11ITH5BSYhxZjvoLhRJ_GA6CI1NMXPr6k

Comment: И что с последним двухместным числом, и с 4-ым от конца (10-местным)?

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers_lst = numbers.split("\n")
only_digits = ["".join([c for c in element if c.isdigit()]) for element in numbers_lst]
formted_lst = [f"{a} ({b}{c}{d}) {e}{f}{g}-{h}{i}-{j}{k}" 
                   for a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k in only_digits[:8]]
result = "\n".join(formted_lst)
print(result)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 8 (963) 672-22-29
> 7 (963) 672-22-29
> 7 (911) 123-12-18
> 7 (915) 221-11-42
> 8 (912) 112-34-55
> 8 (912) 112-34-56
> 7 (912) 112-34-57
> 7 (912) 112-34-57
> ```

---

*Замечание:*

Не все ваше числа 11-местные, потому я применил `only_digits[:8]` вместо простого 
`only_digits`. Когда вы это исправите, уберите `[:8]`.